# Serialization/Encoding in json.NewEncoder and json.NewDecoder

Tags: json, rest, go, backend, encode

I am trying to learn Backend development by building a vary basic REST API using gorilla mux library in Go (following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmiybuiEZI4))

Here's the code that I have built so far:

```
package main

import (
"encoding/json"
"net/http"

"github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

// Post represents single post by user
type Post struct {
Title  string `json:"title"`
Body   string `json:"body"`
Author User   `json:"author"`
}

// User is struct that represnets a user
type User struct {
FullName string `json:"fullName"`
Username string `json:"username"`
Email    string `json:"email"`
}

var posts []Post = []Post{}

func main() {
   router := mux.NewRouter()
   router.HandleFunc("/posts", addItem).Methods("POST")
   http.ListenAndServe(":5000", router)
}

func addItem(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
   var newPost Post
   json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&newPost)

   posts = append(posts, newPost)

   w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
   json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(posts)
}
```

However, I'm really confused about what exactly is happening in `json.NewDecoder` and `json.NewEncoder` part.

As far as I understand, ultimately data transfer over internet in a REST API will happen in form of bytes/binary format (encoded in UTF-8 i guess?). So `json.NewEncoder` is converting Go data strcuture to JSON string and `json.NewDecoder` is doing the opposite (correct me if i'm wrong).

- So who is responsible here for converting this JSON string to UTF-8
  encoding for data transfer? Is that also part of what `json.NewDecoder` and `json.NewEncoder`
  do?
- Also, if these 2 functions are only serializing/de-serializing
  to/from JSON, why the name encoder and decoder (isn't encoding
  always related to binary data conversion?). Honestly i'm pretty confused with the terms `encoding`, `serialization`, `marshaling` and the difference between them

Can someone just explain how exactly is data transfer happening here at each conversion level (json, binary, in-memory data structure)?

Comment: The output JSON string is already UTF-8. UTF-8 is just a text encoding. *All* data, in memory, on desk, in a register, on the wire, anywhere, is bytes. It sounds like you may be overthinking the encoding a bit. As to the terms, you'd have to ask the authors why they chose them, but "encoding", "serialization", and "marshaling" can all be used to refer to the same thing, as can their opposites (plus other terms like "parsing").

Comment: @Adrian I guess my confusion is arising not from Golang specific but data transfer concepts in general. So `json.NewEncoder` is also converting the JSON string to its UTF-8 encoding? Because this is a JSON string : `"{'name': 'John'}"` and this is it's UTF-8 encoding: `\x20\x22\x7b\x27\x6e\x61\x6d\x65\x27\x3a\x20\x27\x4a\x6f\x68\x6e\x27\x7d\x22`
They aren't the same obviously.

Comment: No, `"{'name': 'John'}"` is its UTF-8 encoding. Bytes up to `127` are the same in ASCII and UTF-8.

Comment: Also worth noting, strings in Go are presumed to be UTF-8 by default; and the JSON spec also indicates the JSON documents are presumed UTF-8 by default, and the `encoding/json` documentation states that it follows the JSON spec ([RFC 7195](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159)).

Comment: Okay .. but ultimately wouldn't all data be converted to/from binary? Going from low to high level i think this would be data flow in a `GET` request: `Golang Data structure -> JSON -> UTF-8 -> Binary ------- data transfer over wire -------- Binary -> UTF-8 -> JSON -> JSON.parse in broswer` 
Now this question might be far-fetched but who exactly is responsible for converting to/from binary data here.
Also can you elaborate more on what you mean by every data is bytes?

Comment: UTF-8 *is* binary data. *All* data used by a computer is binary data.

Comment: Okay i was mixing binary conversion with encoding. I guess they have nothing to do with each other

Comment: There simply is no JSON that is not UTF-8. The JSON spec dictates that anything called JSON must be UTF-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, We have to understand that the Encoding process doesn't actually mean that it translates `types` and returns a JSON representation of a `type`. The process that gives you the JSON representation is called the Marshaling process and could be done by calling the [json.Marshal function](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).

On the other hand, the [Encoding](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder.Encode) process means that we want to get the JSON encoding of any `type` and to write(encode) it on a stream that implements io.Writer interface. As we can see the `func NewEncoder(w io.Writer) *Encoder` receives an `io.Writer` interface as a parameter and returns a `*json.Encoder` object. When the method `encoder.Encode()` is being called, it does the Marshaling process and then writes the result to the io.Writer that we have passed when creating a new Encoder object. You could see the implementation of json.Encoder.Encode() [here](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/stream.go?s=5070:5117#L191).

So, if you asked who does do the encoding process to the http stream, the answer is the `http.ResponseWriter`. ResponseWriter implements the io.Writer interface and when the `Encode()` method is being called, the encoder will Marshal the object to a JSON encoding representation and then call the `func Write([]byte) (int, error)` which is a contract method of the io.Writer interface and it will do the writing process to the http stream.

In summary, I could say that Marshal and Unmarshal mean that we want to get the JSON representation of any type and vice-versa. While Encode means that we want to do the Marshaling process and then write(encode) the result to any stream object. And Decode means that we want to get(decode) a json object from any stream and then do the Unmarshaling process.

Comment: But won't data always be transferred in a stream? 

If so, why would there be any situation where we need to use marshal/unmarshal instead of encoder/decoder?

Comment: @V_S_X the marshaling process returns a JSON representation of any type in a slice of byte. It will be very useful when we want to do another process to the json data. For example, when the data needs to be encrypted or when we want to get the hash sum of the JSON encoded data. The crypto.sha512sum function recieves an array of byte as its parameter and it will be the case where we need the Marshaling instead of Encoding process.

Answer (score 2):

1. The `json.Encoder` produced by the call to `json.NewEncoder` directly produces its output in UTF-8.  No conversion is necessary.  (In fact, Go does not have a representation for textual data that is distinct from UTF-8 encoded sequences of bytes — even a `string` is just an immutable array of bytes under the hood.)
2. Go uses the term *encode* for serialisation and *decode* for deserialisation, whether the serialised form is binary or textual.  Do not think too much about the terminology — consider *encode* and *seralise* as synonyms.

Comment: So does this mean that Go always stores any data structure in UTF-8 encoded bytes in memory?

Comment: No, only textual data (strings).

Comment: `even a string is just an immutable array of bytes under the hood` .... sorry but i don't have any experience with any other BE languages ... how else can a string be stored in memory eg. in java or C++?? Isn't string immutable in java too?

Comment: In Java and Javascript, strings are stored as sequences of 16-bit values interpreted as UTF-16.  Thus, it is not easy to store arbitrary binary binary data in Java or Javascript strings.  Similary, in Python 3 the type `string` has some weird representation, you need to use `bytes` in order to store arbitrary binary data.